# Terminal shortcut to go to beginning of command?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

For example, forgetting to put `sudo` and having to go back to the beginning of the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Home. Plus you may want to know about `sudo !!`, which repeats the previous command, but with `sudo` in front of it.

Answer (score 3):

**CTRL + a**

(tends not to work if you using SCREEN though since screen uses Ctrl-A as a control switch.)